# PHP Variable value based on user input

Tags: php, math, calculator

I'm building an application to help customer calculate various product prices.

Right now I'm building a feature where user enters a single number to the application and submits a form. Based on that number, I would like to define another variables value.

**What I'd like to achieve**

If user input is number between **1-10**, set variable number to **200**.

If user input is number between **11-20**, set variable number to **400**.

If user input is number between **21-30**, set variable number to **600**.

If user input is number between **31-40**, set variable number to **800**.

If user input is number between **41-50**, set variable number to **1000**.

**And so on...** So basically increasing by 200 every tenth.
Of course, I could do something like this:

```
$userInput = 11;
$result;

if($userInput => 1 && $userInput =< 10)
$result = 200;

if($userInput => 11 && $userInput =< 20)
$result = 400;

if($userInput => 21 && $userInput =< 30)
$result = 600;
```

But it isn't really a great solution, because it takes lot of code and if user sets number out of the determined range it doesn't work..

How can I implement this with as little amount of code as possible?

Comment: I think this question is better post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, anyway set max/min to input  will solve one of your problem

Comment: _"So basically increasing by 200 every tenth"_ You've just described the algorithm for your solution. Write that sentence in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have the math right, you just need to divide the number by 10, and use [ceil](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round the fraction up. From there, multiply it by 200;

```
function getVariable($num) {
    $divisor = ceil($num / 10);
    return $divisor * 200;
}


echo getVariable(1)."\n"; // 200
echo getVariable(6)."\n"; // 200
echo getVariable(13)."\n"; // 400
echo getVariable(27)."\n"; // 600
echo getVariable(48)."\n"; // 1000
echo getVariable(50)."\n"; // 1000
echo getVariable(88)."\n"; // 1800
echo getVariable(100)."\n"; // 2000
```